# PHP Array Value to Array ID

Tags: php, wordpress, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to use WP function get_page_title with page_ID.

Its look like this.

**FROM**

```
array (
    0 => 'Home',
    1 => 101,
    2 => 'About',
    3 => 102,
    4 => 'Portfolio',
    5 => 103,
    6 => 'Price',
    7 => 104,
    8 => 'Contact',
    9 => 105,
)
```

**TO**

```
array (
    '101' => 'Home',
    '102' => 'About',
    '103' => 'Portfolio',
    '104' => 'Price',
    '105' => 'Contact',
)
```

**example**

```
array (
    'page_ID' => 'page_title',
)
```

Comment: Try to at least show an attempt of what you've done. SO isn't a code writing service, the experience is better for both of us if you provide us with at least some form of attempt

Comment: What are the logic with key 359?

Comment: Where is `104` & `105` in your array?

Comment: **page id** and **page title**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your keys are always in odd indexes, and you values are always in even indexes, and you have the same numbers of each you can do:

```
$data = array (
    0 => 'Home',
    1 => 101,
    2 => 'About',
    3 => 102,
    4 => 'Portfolio',
    5 => 103,
    6 => 'Price',
    7 => 104,
    8 => 'Contact',
    9 => 105,
);

$values = array_filter($data, function($key) {
    return $key % 2 == 0;
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
$keys = array_filter($data, function($key) {
    return $key % 2 == 1;
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);


var_dump(array_combine($keys, $values));
```

Output:

```
array (size=5)
    101 => string 'Home' (length=4)
    102 => string 'About' (length=5)
    103 => string 'Portfolio' (length=9)
    104 => string 'Price' (length=5)
    105 => string 'Contact' (length=7)
```

Alternatively, you can sort then mount the array

```
//the string will be in the beggining and the numbers at the end
sort($data, SORT_NUMERIC); //important SORT_NUMERIC to not mix the string values

$data = array_combine(array_slice($data, count($data)/2), array_slice($data, 0, count($data)/2));
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be overkill, but if there are always the same number of ids and titles and titles don't start with a number:

```
$array = array_combine(preg_grep('/^\d+/', $array), preg_grep('/^[a-z]+/i', $array));
```

Comment: I like this solution, but it isn't working here. The second preg_grep returns the entire array. A possible solution would be `preg_grep('/[^0-9]+/', $array)`

Comment: It was `[a-z]` as `\w` got them all.  Thanks.

Comment: No problem. Now it works, if there isn't special chars in the beginning, like `'Ãbout'`

Answer (score 0):

I'm making the same assumption other people have about there always being an even number of elements in the array and it being arranged in value/key/value/key/etc order, but this is a pretty clean option:

```
$output = [];

while ($data && ($v = array_shift($data)) && ($k = array_shift($data))) {
  $output[$k] = $v;
}
```

See https://3v4l.org/GvGQU

Answer (score 0):

Just another way to do that without array_filter and array_shift functions:

```
$i = 0;

while ($i < count($arr)) {
    $val = $arr[$i++];
    $key = $arr[$i++];
    empty($key) ?: $new_arr[$key] = $val;
}
```

https://3v4l.org/cSYcc